# What is the purpose of the @prompt instance variable in irb (using Cloud9 IDE)?

Tags: ruby, ide, cloud9-ide, irb

During a session in irb:

```
instance_variables #=> [:@prompt]
```

inspecting `@prompt` reveals a hash:

```
{:PROMPT_I=>"2.1.4 :%03n > ", :PROMPT_S=>"2.1.4 :%03n%l> ", :PROMPT_C=>"2.1.4 
 :%03n > ", :PROMPT_N=>"2.1.4 :%03n?> ", :RETURN=>" => %s \n", 
 :AUTO_INDENT=>true}
```

What is the role of the instance variable `@prompt` and the key/value pairs in its hash? *(For reference I'm using Ruby 2.1.4 on a Cloud9 IDE)*

Comment: I don't see it,  using Ruby 2.1.7

Comment: You've made me think. It must be because I'm using a cloud based IDE. I just checked my Iocal 'real' irb and can't reproduce either. I will update my question and add relevant tags.

Comment: Yes, read about "Customizing the IRB Prompt" [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html)